# query dsl how to construct nested list

Tags: java, hibernate, querydsl

So I have simple dto object that conatins part of entity data. The problem is how to create using query dsl those two list below.

```
public class DtoPackageData implements Serializable {
    private final String policyNumber;
    private final String status;
    private final List<Payment> payments;
    private final List<Role> roles;
}
```

At the moment i am using to constuct non list fields as:

```
return constructor(DtoPackageData.class,
        contract.policyNumber,
        contract.status)
```

but how to create those two list? I already tried something like:

```
return constructor(DtoPackageData.class,
        contract.policyNumber,
        contract.status,
        list(Dto.class, payment.amountDue, payment.primaryKey.dueDate, payment.amountPaid));
//payment is joined as join(contract.payments, payment)
```

but it seems that this list function return object instead of list of objects and there is no mathing constructor.